# boxplot in R - Ploting boxplot explained

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I'm using sample codes from StackOverflow about how to plot a boxplot with the values and I near of what I want.

1. How to plot a boxplot with name of each value on boxplot like [this](https://flowingdata.com/2008/02/15/how-to-read-and-use-a-box-and-whisker-plot/).
2. The following code below is a junction of sample codes from
   Stackoverflow and is working fine to plot a boxplot on horizontal
   way with the numbers, but I want to plot in a vertical way. If I
   just change the parameter horizontal = FALSE, the values of each
   quartile is not printing.

`myData<-c(3,12,20,25,30,35,70,70,80,150)`

```
boxplot(
  myData,
  show.names = TRUE,
  names = "Graph name 01",
  axes = TRUE,
  horizontal = FALSE,
  col = "red",
  staplewex = 1,
  main = "My main title",
  sub = "My subtitle",
  xlab = "X title",
  ylab = "Y title",
  outline = TRUE
)
text(
  x = boxplot.stats(myData)$stats,
  labels = boxplot.stats(myData)$stats,
  y = 1.25
)
```

Can someone give me a hint on those 2 questions?

Comment: 2) Just swap `x` and `y`.

Comment: Tks Rui, worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

In the link that you send you are graphing the quartiles, minimum, medium and maximum, so this safe code will serve you.

```
myData<-c(3,12,20,25,30,35,70,70,80,150)

boxplot(
  myData,
  show.names = TRUE,
  names = "Graph name 01",
  axes = TRUE,
  horizontal = FALSE,
  col = "red",
  staplewex = 1,
  main = "My main title",
  sub = "My subtitle",
  xlab = "X title",
  ylab = "Y title",
  outline = TRUE
)

points(x=1,y=mean(myData), pch = 5)
text(x= 1.3, y= summary(myData), labels= paste(names(summary(myData)),summary(myData)))
```

Comment: Tks a lot Rafael Diaz.